# How to escape single quote in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Given the following resource in an AzureRM template, how would one encode the single quote in the `commandToExecute` part?

```json
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmNameMaster'), copyIndex(), '/sethost')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "copy": {
      "name": "extensionLoopNode",
      "count": "[variables('masterCount')]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmNameMaster'), copyIndex(),'/extensions/DockerExtension')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [ ],
      "commandToExecute": "[concat('/bin/bash -c \'echo \"export DOCKER_HOST=:2375\" >> /home/', parameters('adminUsername') ,'/.profile\'')]",
      "timestamp": 123456789
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping using \. i.e. "commandToExecute": "[concat('/bin/bash -c \'echo \"export DOCKER_HOST=:2375\" >> /home/\', parameters(\'adminUsername\') ,\'/.profile\'')]"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've worked around this with a variable:

```json
"variables": {
    "singleQuote": "'",
},
...
"settings": {
    "fileUris": [],
    "commandToExecute": "[concat('/bin/bash -c ', variables('singleQuote'), 'echo \"export DOCKER_HOST=:2375\" >> /home/', parameters('adminUsername') ,'/.profile', variables('singleQuote'))]",
}
```

It isn't elegant but it works.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me a bunch of time

Comment: how is this an answer when `''` is?

Answer (score 63):

You escape Azure ARM functions in the same way as with VB strings: you simply double the single quote characters.

```
[concat('This is a ''quoted'' word.')]
```

outputs

```
This is a 'quoted' word.
```

---

Double quotes still needs to be escaped from JSON.

```
 [concat('''single'' and \"double\" quotes.')]
```

outputs

```
'single' and "double" quotes.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the currently accepted answer is not as elegant.

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studio will view this as an error: Expected a comma. It may work, but you will have to ignore the red squiggle. A lot of people will find this unacceptable.

Comment: this didn't work for me. So I'll have to resort to the less elegant solution :)

Comment: While deploying resources in Azure Synapse using ARM templates I found that [concat('This is a ''quoted'' word.')] became "This is a ''quoted'' word" for some annoying reason. The accepted answer worked in that case.

Answer (score 2):

In DevOps release pipeline, for APIM policy, use & quote; to escape quotes within an expression,

```
<when condition='@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault&lt;bool&gt;(&quot;isAuthOk&quot;))' />
```

Answer (score -4):

it is not necessary encode the single quote in the commandToExecute part.
The json segment below has been validated as valid json in 
http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute / virtualMachines / extensions ",
    "name": "[concat(variables('vmNameMaster'), copyIndex(), '/sethost')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "copy": {
        "name": "extensionLoopNode",
        "count": "[variables('masterCount')]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmNameMaster'), copyIndex(),'/extensions/DockerExtension')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
        "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
        "settings": {
            "fileUris": [],
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('/bin/bash -c 'echo \"export DOCKER_HOST=:2375\" >> /home/', parameters('adminUsername') ,'/.profile'')]",
            "timestamp": 123456789
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but it is not valid a valid arm template

Comment: What is the error you get and what is your ARM template json schema?

Comment: here is the schema: http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#. Problem is, arm will recognize the single quote as its own processing directive ...

Comment: this will not work as un-escaped single quotes are reserved for template functions in ARM templates.