# ARM Template Custom Script Extension with paramaters that have a space

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

`powershell -File './scripts/myscript.ps1' -Param1 "My Param"`

Whats the syntax needed to deploy a custom script extension that invokes a PowerShell file with params that have a space in them. These are what I've tried so far and none of them have worked. Each of these are as they were in my ARM template:

```
# Failed to being executing the script. Error from the logs on the VM: "VMExtensionProvisioningError"
"[concat('powershell -File InstallVSTSAgent.ps1 -vstsAccount \"', parameters('vstsAccount'), '\"')]"

# Failed in the same way.
"[concat('powershell -File InstallVSTSAgent.ps1 -vstsAccount \\\"', parameters('vstsAccount'), '\\\"')]"

# Ran, but the parameters entering my PowerShell file were wrapped in `ticks`
"[concat('powershell -File InstallVSTSAgent.ps1 -vstsAccount `\"', parameters('vstsAccount'), '`\"')]"
```

Comment: first one should work, I don't think the problem is in the template.

Comment: @4c74356b41 - you are correct. I tried it again and it worked. It must have been a different issue in my script I fixed earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variant of escaping was correct. To escape in ARM template use `\`

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to hold the quote, then concat the string you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293130/84395

```
"variables": {
    "singleQuote": "'",
},
...
"[concat('powershell -File InstallVSTSAgent.ps1 -vstsAccount ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('vstsAccount'), variables('singleQuote'))]"
```