# How to escape single quotes in ARM Template with @concat function

Tags: java, azure, azure-rm-template

I have template for datafactory pipeline with destination dataset sink, which I want deploy using resource manager and Java Azure SDK:

```
{
      "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/', parameters('pipeline_pipelineConfiguration_pipelineTemplate_destinationDataset01'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "[parameters('pipeline_pipelineConfiguration_pipelineTemplate_destinationLinkedService01')]",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
            "fileName": {
              "value": "[concat('@concat(utcnow(\'yyyy-MM-dd\'),\'-',parameters('pipeline_pipelineConfiguration_destination'),',.txt\'')]",
              "type": "Expression"
            },
            "container": ""
          },
          "columnDelimiter": ",",
          "escapeChar": "\\",
          "firstRowAsHeader": true,
          "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/', parameters('pipeline_pipelineConfiguration_pipelineTemplate_DestinationLinkedService01'))]"
      ]
    }
```

I get exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape ''' (code 39)
```

most probably because of *value* parameter for *fileName*.

What would the best way to provide file name with date calculated on time of exporting data and part of the name taken from parameter ?

Comment: Try to create a variable for singleQuote. refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986180/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-arm-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable and make calculation of value this variable
or use replace() function.